# Accessing instantiated resources from another script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For context, I have instantiated multiple GameObjects over time which represent the score in my game. I know how to change the position where they are instantiated.

```
string scoreText = score.ToString ();

for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++)
    {
var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString()));

go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.02F + i * 0.01F, 0.13F, 0);
}
```

What I don't know how to do is change the position in another script. Again, for context, on Game Over in the other script, I want to change the position of these objects I instantiated.

I have tried multiple variations of GetComponent and GameObject. I can't pin down one GameObject that I want to access, because it is multiple, ever changing GameObjects. I feel like I am not looking at this right. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well one way to go would be to make your GameObject variable **go** a class variable so that you can access it in other methods. But if you spawn many objects you can make an array of GameObjects and then iterate through them with to find one you need. You can make the array a public variable so that other scripts can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The other scripts can access the data of your script that is `public` and `static`, so the first step is to create a variable that will hold your score in the main script:

```
public static GameObject[] Score;
```

During the initialization, use this variable to save the score:

```
string scoreText = score.ToString ();

Score = new GameObject[scoreText.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++)
{
    Score[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString()));
    Score[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.02F + i * 0.01F, 0.13F, 0);
}
```

At this point, inside the game over script, you should be able to use the score data from the main script (if this doesn't work, make sure you are using the right namespaces and references, but if the two scripts are in the same project there shouldn't be any problems):

```
MainScript.Score //MainScript is the name of your main script
```

If you want to iterate over the score in the game over script:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MainScript.Score.Length; i++)
{
    MainScript.Score[i] = do something here...
}
```